# Получить переменную файла .php с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть страница index.php

```
<?php
//CODE
?>
```

Есть страница result.php:

```
<?php
$res = "Результат";
echo $res;
?>
```

Подскажите, как с помощью AJAX запроса вывести "Результат" на страницу index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл `index.php`:

```php
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>
<div>Основная страница</div>
<div>Параметр с другой страницы:</div>
<div id="param"></div>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() { // Отслеживаем полную загрузку документа
        $.ajax({ // Готовим ajax запрос
            url: "result.php",  // Указываем файл, к которому обращаемся
            method: "GET", // Указываем метод, который необходимо использовать.
            success: function(data) { // Если успешно запрос отправлен и данные получены.
                console.log(data); // Возвращаемые данные выводим в консоль
                $('#param').text(data); // Добавляем значение в поле с id = param
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Второй файл `result.php`:

```php
<?php
$res = "Результат";
echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А можете пожалуйста прокомментировать строчки, которые касаются именно ajax'a? Буду Вам очень благодарен.

Comment: @Максим Закревский Добавил )

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!